# Serenity.ComponentModel.RadioButtonEditor using a const string value

Tags: serenity-platform

I have a class of constant (string). I would like to use as radio button but it only accept a lookup (database) and enum (int). Is there any workaround to have a radio button for a string value?

Answer (score 0):

Serenity doesn't have editor for this. You can write your own radio button editor which get id as string with same value of text and string value.
Check editor samples in basic samples > editors. You can inherit radio button editor and override functions as you expect.